Does the RESTORE CURSOR escape sequence also restore formatting?
When using the save/restore cursor escape sequences \e7 & \e8, I find that it not only restores the cursor position, but it also restores the text formatting (colors).
I've tried under WSL, vscode in Windows, and in an online Ubuntu VM. Is this standardized (for some value of 'standard')? Can it be relied on in most terminals in use today?

You can't even be sure that ESC 7 and ESC 8 will save/restore the position!  Not all terminals follow the same standard.  Which is why Unix has a terminfo (and previously termcap) database to let programs discover what each terminal can do.
Ideally you should use the terminfo capabilities "sc" (save cursor) and "rc" (restore cursor) to get the values, for more portability.  Very likely they'll be \E7 and \E8 but you can't be sure.
So, for example
% infocmp -1 | egrep '    [sr]c='
        rc=\E8,
        sc=\E7,

But an old terminfo definition for mskermit227|msk227|MS-DOS Kermit 2.27 for the IBMPC has sc=\Ej and rc=\Ek.
A sperry uts30 has rc=\EX and sc=\EW.
Some terminal types don't even support this functionality at all!  Looking at the terminfo definitions on my CentOS 7 machine lists 16 definitions without this support.
Are you likely to come across these terminal types?  Possibly not (although one is "xterm-vt52"; someone picking that is just trying to make life hard for themselves...).  Most modern terminals and terminal emulators (the remaining 103 in my terminfo list) all support it.
Now, really ESC 7 and ESC 8 are DEC mode commands that come from the VT series.  For this the description is a bit more explicit:

ESC 8 - DECRC - DEC Restore Cursor - Restores the cursor position, encoding shift state and formatting attributes from the previous DECSC if any, otherwise resets these all to their defaults

So for any terminal emulator that properly implements this, we can be confident it will reset colour and bold/dim attributes.
For safety purposes, though, you shouldn't assume this; after an "rc" call you should explicitly set any formatting you want to continue.
